# Converting DataTable to Generic List<T>

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to convert a Data table to a generic List. I am following this post. [DataTable to List<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709035/datatable-to-listobject).

```
Method is 
 public static List<MProps> TableToList<T1>(DataTable dt)
        {
                if (dt == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            List<DataRow> rows = new List<DataRow>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return TableToList<T1>(rows);
        }

I keep getting two errors at "return TableToList<T1>(rows);" Saying 
Error 24 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Data.DataTable' C:\Users..\Program.cs    

AND 

Error 23 The best overloaded method match for 'xx.Program.TableToList<T1>(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\--\Program.cs
```

I cant figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
List<DataRow> rows = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

If you need to return List

```
return (from DataRow row in dt.Rows
   select new MProps
   {
       //assign properties here
       prop1 = row["colname"].ToString()
   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `return`, you're trying to call the method again, but you're passing `rows`, which is a `List<DataRow>`.  Your method expects a `DataTable`, so it's telling you that you're calling your method incorrectly.

Theoretically, you should be making a `List<MProps>` and returning that, rather than making a `List<DataRow>` and calling `TableToList`.  Perhaps make a `DataRowToMProp` method and call that for every `DataRow`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var lst = from x in dt.AsEnumerable() 
where x.Field <string>("PersonName") == "ching" select x;
```