# how to use replace function with in clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want sql query which gives output as concat string

**Sql Query**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(nm) FROM xyz WHERE xyz.id IN (REPLACE(abc,"|",','))
```

where abc is string like 1|2|3|4 which is ids of xyz table 
above query only gives nm of 1st id in abc.I thing it creates query like

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(nm) FROM xyz WHERE xyz.id IN ("1,2,3,4")
```

so (") may creates problem anyone can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL IN Clause In Stored Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354287/sql-in-clause-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: @ChrisGessler - This is tagged MySQL, the question you linked in SQL Server.

Comment: @Dems - still related to dynamic IN clauses and mentions several solutions like implementing a split function, etc... same techniques could easly be applied to MySql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LIKE`, (but then its not going to use indexs)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(nm)
FROM xyz
WHERE CONCAT('|', abc, '|') LIKE CONCAT('%|', xyz.id, '|%');
```

Comment: Does MySQL have User Defined Table Valued Functions?  So the OP can use `WHERE id IN ((SELECT split(@list, `,`))`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INSTR` like so:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(nm) 
FROM xyz 
WHERE INSTR(CONCAT('|', abc, '|'), CONCAT('|', xyz.id, '|')) > 0
```

Or you could implement a split function or use dynamic SQL.

Comment: is there a speed diference between instr and like?

Comment: @AndriyM i know LIKE can do more then INSTR, but if you only need the functionality of INSTR, do i get a faster query with INSTR, or can i keep using LIKE as im used to

Comment: @PugganSe: Yes, that's what I missed in your question and that's why I removed my comment. I hoped you wouldn't see it and I was wrong. :) Sorry about that piece of silliness of mine.