# Multiple table updates - avoiding multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I looked around for a similar question (I'm sure there is one somewhere) but could not find one.

I have a list of IDs that for each of the IDs I need to update another column of that IDs row to the same string.

Essentially, I want something like this:

```
List<int> uniqueIDs;

UPDATE my_table
SET certainColumn = "foo bar"
WHERE uniqueID = uniqueIDs[0]
    OR uniqueID = uniqueIDs[1]
    ...
    OR uniqueID = uniqueID[uniqueIDs.Length-1]
```

I know this could be achieved by surrounding this in a for/foreach-loop, but I was wondering if there is a better way to get this done, possibly in one database connection?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your example has a line of C# followed by an SQL statement - Are you trying to achieve this in C# or in SQL? Or you want to figure out how to pass the list to SQL in one shot?

Comment: Great question. I was mostly just combining the two to better show my end goal. I would like to formulate some sql update in C# and then execute it. So the latter I guess!

Comment: Will you be updating a `certainColumn` for multiple uniqueID ?? and you have a list of them uniqueIDs ?? correct me if I am wrong ??

Comment: My suggestion would be a hybrid approach. Look into table valued parameters in SQL 2008 or higher. You can pass a table (custom defined table type in SQL) from c# and then just use a simple IN clause in your WHERE clause, encapsulated in a stored procedure.

Comment: @M.Ali you're correct. Multiple rows will need the certainColumn to be updated to "foo bar."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could use a TVP. First, create this on your server:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.UniqueIDs AS TABLE(ID INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then a stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateByID
  @tvp dbo.UniqueIDs READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE t SET certainColumn = 'foo bar'
    FROM dbo.my_table AS t
    INNER JOIN @tvp AS tvp
    ON t.uniqueID = tvp.ID;
END
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateByID
  @tvp dbo.UniqueIDs READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE t SET certainColumn = 'foo bar'
    FROM dbo.my_table AS t
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @tvp
      WHERE ID = t.uniqueID);
END
```

Then instead of a `List` use a `DataTable` to hold your IDs in your C# application, and call the stored procedure, passing `@tvp` as a `Structured` parameter. I have simple examples of the C# side posted all over this site:

- [How to pass an array into a SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10405622/61305)
- [Insert entire DataTable into database at once instead of row by row?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10405622/61305)
- [Parameters to the EXISTS clause in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10744731/61305)

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = "UPDATE my_table
SET certainColumn = 'foo bar'
WHERE uniqueID in (" + String.Join(",", uniqueIDs) + ")"
```

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a character limit on the length of a query string? There is a possibility (but not likely) of up to about 5000 updates, which would mean (5000 * 2) extra characters in the query counting the commas. Hopefully not, because I like this solution.

Comment: Just because you can create a SQL string that is 100 KB and has an IN list of 5000 items doesn't mean you should IMHO.

Comment: @njenson I can think of quite a few limits. My advice is to create a temporary variable using good practice and then use a where clause, like a proper programmer should do

Comment: I do agree with the two above comments. Though it all depends on your scenario. If it's not really an important application I would just leave it like this, and my feeling is that it isn't, because who would still be concatenating strings for any serious app???

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do something like this.  Get your List of Ids in some TempTable or table variable and use `IN` operator in your update statement. something like this .....

```
UPDATE my_table
SET certainColumn = 'foo bar'
WHERE uniqueID IN (SELECT uniqueID 
                   FROM @List_Table)
```