# How do I insert Rows from my DATASET to my DATABASE without using command builder?

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, dataset, oledb

I have a database with multiple tables each linked to the other.(Relational Database) 
I want to Insert Records from my Dataset to Database.
First I tried using OledbCommandBuilder but that didn't work, I found out it couldn't work with relational databases.
I haven't linked tables within my dataset, they are linked only in the database.
What I have is a button named "Commit". When I press that button I want all the modifications in my dataset.datatable to be reflected in the respective database table. 
I only know how to INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE a single record at a time but that also is a lengthy task as first I have to do this.

CODE IN THE SAVE BUTTON

```
             DataRow dRow = bookDS.Tables["Book"].NewRow();

               dRow[0] = Convert.ToInt64(textBookID.Text);
               dRow[1] = textBookName.Text;
               dRow[2] = textISBN.Text;
```

and so on (there are 30 columns)

```
              bookDS.Tables["Book"].Rows.Add(dRow);
```

Then

CODE IN THE COMMIT BUTTON

con.Open();

```
                    string sql = "Insert INTO Book Values (@BookId, @BookName, @ISBNNo, @PublicationId, @CategoryId, @Pages,@Price,@Author1,@Author2,@TotalCopies,@IssuedCopies,@AvailableCopies,@SupplierName,@Note)";

                    OleDbCommand save = new OleDbCommand(sql);

                    save.Parameters.Add("@BookId", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt64(dRow[0]);
                    save.Parameters.Add("@BookName", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = dRow[1];
                    save.Parameters.Add("@ISBNNo", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = dRow[2];
```

and so on...

save.Connection = con;
                        save.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
                    con.Close();
```

That is all i can think of but that only works for a single Row and so I its like I have to press the COMMIT button every time I press the SAVE button.

Can anyone please help me with this ???

P.S : I am using MSAccess and also don't want to use TABLEADAPTER ( I want to do everything  with my code )

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x.aspx

Try using OleDBDataAdapter for this job.
Or you can even try using OleDBComamndBuilder (of OleDb for Access database instead of Sql):

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/380925/how-to-save-a-dataset-into-a-database

Comment: I cannot use OLEDBCommandBuilder as the tables in the database are related. I know I can use OledbAdapter but there would be multiple records to insert/update/delete into the database rather than one.

Answer (score 0):

```
       string sql = "Insert INTO Book Values (@BookId, @BookName, @ISBNNo, @PublicationId, @CategoryId, @Pages,@Price,@Author1,@Author2,@TotalCopies,@IssuedCopies,@AvailableCopies,@SupplierName,@Note)";

     DataRow dRow = bookDS.Tables["Book"].NewRow();

                   dRow[0] = Convert.ToInt64(textBookID.Text);
                   dRow[1] = textBookName.Text;
                   dRow[2] = textISBN.Text;
                   bookDS.Tables["Book"].Rows.Add(dRow);
//This would help you to commit all the changes at once.   
 bookDS.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: bookDS.AcceptChanges() would only change the RowState property of the dataset.tables[0] and the changes are not reflected in the database !

Comment: @WaqasAli:Ok,view this page :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405373/insert-entire-datatable-into-database-at-once-instead-of-row-by-row