# How can a Deedle dataframe be inserted into a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataframe, deedle

Is there an easy way to take data from a Deedle dataframe and insert it into an existing SQL Server table using C#?

Answer (score 2):

There is [a `ToDataTable` extension method](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-frameextensions.html#section3). available on data frames.

This gives you a fairly simple way to get all the data from a data frame and it should not be hard to find code samples showing how to insert data from a `DataTable` into SQL database.

- One SO answer showing this is: [Insert entire DataTable into database at once instead of row by row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405373/insert-entire-datatable-into-database-at-once-instead-of-row-by-row)