# Insert datatable into existing Access file

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I want to select content from an existing SQL Server and store the Information in an existing Access file. How can i easily update the table in my file?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've got it to work row by row but wanted to know if it is possible to send a complete datatable to another database table

Comment: Please referlink: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405373/insert-entire-datatable-into-database-at-once-instead-of-row-by-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, your best bet is to let Access do the work with built-in tools.  I would link the SQL Server table to your Access DB, and then create a Make-Table query in Access that creates a new table from your linked SQL Server table.  You can pull the whole table or just a subset of it, depending on how you set up your query.