# Bulk Copy of DataTable into a DB Table

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, ibm-midrange, sqlbulkcopy

I saw this [great](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20108861/5050203) answer on how to insert a DataTable to DB using SqlBulkCopy.
I need to insert a DataTable into a AS400 table (IBM Version 7.1.0).
I am searching for a similar solution using OdbcConnection.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzatd/rzatdfinder.htm)

- "Accessing data with ODBC" or
- "Accessing data with IBM i Access for Windows .Net Provider"
- "Accessing data with Net.Data"

[image: Screen Shot of IBM Knowledge Center with "ODBC" Highlighted]]

Answer (score 0):

FWiW: The Copy From Import File (CPYFRMIMPF) is the *parallel data loader* feature provided by the DB2 for i, as part of the IBM i OS; imports data previously exported, clearly not what was expressed in the OP, but perhaps worthwhile information nonetheless.