# Insert rows within transaction with FK to first row created

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions

I've got a batch of rows that need to be inserted within a single transaction, the first row is a header and all subsequent rows must reference the first.

This is how I'm attempting to insert the first row:

```
using ( var connection = new SqlConnection( _connectionString ) )
{
    connection.Open();
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        // create the record header
        using ( var createRecordCommand = connection.CreateCommand() )
        {
            createRecordCommand.CommandText =
                "DECLARE @RecordId INT;" +
                $"INSERT INTO ..." +
                "SET @RecordId = scope_identity();";

            createRecordCommand.Transaction = transaction;
            createRecordCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'm struggling to reference RecordId in subsequent statements, it seems to think the variable @RecordId is not declared in the snippet below. **'Must declare the scalar variable "@RecordId".'**

```
using ( var createAttributeCommand = connection.CreateCommand() )
{
    createAttributeCommand.Transaction = transaction;

    createAttributeCommand.CommandText =
        $"INSERT INTO ... (RecordId,...) VALUES (@RecordId,...)";
```

Also extracting the @RecordId variable as a parameter is proving difficult, it doesn't like it when I use the below line in conjunction with `DECLARE @RecordId INT;`

```
createRecordCommand.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter( "@RecordId", SqlDbType.Int ) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output } );
```

Comment: Why don't you put your logic into a stored procedure and then just call the procedure from C#?

Comment: I've shaved allot of the complexity out of the question, what we're trying to achieve is too complex for a stored proc unfortunately.

Comment: Ummm what? Too complex for a stored procedure? Do the insert as a stored procedure and use an OUTPUT parameter to return the identity.

Comment: Use bulkcopy.   See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405373/insert-entire-datatable-into-database-at-once-instead-of-row-by-row/20108861#20108861

Comment: You need to return the ReportID to your code or combe the second insert in with your first command. I think Rigerta is right. Use a sproc. 
Or, if you use the output operator on your insert you could return the scope_identity and then add the value to the parameter for your subsequent call. `createRecordCommand.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter( "@RecordId", SqlDbType.Int ) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output , value = ReportIDValue} );`

Comment: @SeanLange You can't create a stored procedure with a variable number of parameters AFAIK, unless you parse parameters from XML or CSV, while not impossible to achieve with a stored procedure, it would involve rebuilding a bunch of stuff in SQL, this isn't appropriate at this stage, we're still prototyping.

Comment: I would at least consider the possibility that the process needs to be rethought. Since you are still in the prototyping phase maybe this is possible. A variable number of parameters being required is a pretty good indication that something is a bit left of center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't realised you can extract data before the transaction was committed, assuming that since ExecuteScalar() didn't work, I'd run into the same issue.

As pointed out in the comments, a stored procedure is probably the best solution, SQL experts sound like broken records after a while ;p. This will be too complex short term as there are variable # of parameters, validation and values will mutate based on business logic. As a team, we're more comfortable in C# so that's where the logic will remain until it's completely nailed down.

Resulting code is as follows, **N.B. in real code, pass all variables as parameters to avoid SQL injection, we are, this is demonstration only**:

```
using ( var connection = new SqlConnection( _connectionString ) )
{
    connection.Open();
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        // create the record header
        using ( var createRecordCommand = connection.CreateCommand() )
        {
            createRecordCommand.CommandText =
                //"DECLARE @RecordId INT;" + 
                $"INSERT INTO ..." +
                "SET @RecordId = scope_identity();";

            createRecordCommand.Transaction = transaction;
            createRecordCommand.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter( "@RecordId", SqlDbType.Int ) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output } );
            createRecordCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            recordId = (int) createRecordCommand.Parameters["@RecordId"].Value;

// ...

using ( var createAttributeCommand = connection.CreateCommand() )
{
    createAttributeCommand.Transaction = transaction;
    createAttributeCommand.CommandText =
        $"INSERT INTO ... (RecordId,...) VALUES ({recordId},...)";

// ...

transaction.Commit();
```