# How to insert data from excel file into microsoft localdb database using C#

Tags: c#, sql, excel, database, localdb

I am trying to insert data from exel files to Microsoft SQL server local db table.
I can show a dataGridview with the excel data in a windows form application but I cant figure out how to put the data into a table.

```
try
{   
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection cnn;
    System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter cmd;

    cnn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\\CGData\\user\\Desktop\\Book1.xls';Extended Properties = Excel 8.0");
    cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [sheet1$]", cnn);
    cmd.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
    DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
    cmd.Fill(DtSet);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
    cnn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

What Else do I need to do to copy the Data into a  localDB Database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a datatable (DtSet.Tables[0]), all you need is to bulkcopy that datatable to SQL.
check this answer: 
[Insert entire DataTable into database at once instead of row by row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405373/insert-entire-datatable-into-database-at-once-instead-of-row-by-row)