# User defined table type with dynamic columns in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In my .NET (C#) win application, I import an Excel file that contains multiple columns of varying numbers. So, I store the data in my `datatable` in code and I need to pass that `datatable` to a SQL Server stored procedure for further processing.

Is there any proper way to pass my `datatable` to a SQL Server stored procedure and can user defined table type have a dynamic number of columns?

Comment: you can create a global temp table and access it from the stored procedure.

Comment: @SerkanArslan can you please share more details about global temp table and how do i access. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> if it's possible to create a table type with a dynamic number of
>   columns.

No, its not possible.

My suggestion would be you can update the data from `datatable` directly to sql server table like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20108861/3349551), then use the table in your procedure.

```
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(_connection.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
{
      // my DataTable column names match my SQL Column names, so I simply made this loop. However if your column names don't match, just pass in which datatable name matches the SQL column name in Column Mappings
      foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
      {
          bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
      }

      bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
      bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
      bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

Note, `datatable` column name should be same as your sql table column name to get it mapped properly.

Comment: My problem is i dont have fixed columns, my columns can be differ each time i import excel.

Comment: @SyedWahhab - Do you know all possible column names ? Each time it could be different columns present in excel, but do you have the full list of possible columns

Comment: I have a property data and their borrowers can be multiple one property may have Two borrowers and other property may have 15 borrowers, lets assume a maximum number of borrowers (50) at a single property, should i create a 50 columns and then utilize as per availability of data? PS: I cannot pass data in comma separated values for multiple column

Comment: @SyedWahhab - Yeah, thats the idea.

Comment: According to me, you should use JSON to store data in database. You don't need to create multiple columns for borrowers. Create a column in table which will be of size max and store all your borrowers in JSON format in that column wrt property.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, you can not create a table with a dynamic number of
>   columns.

You can use JSON to store all your borrowers in a single column. You really don't need to create multiple columns for borrowers. You can simply create a column in a table that will be of size `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and you have to create a JSON of all borrowers and store it in a table.

While retrieving data from the table deserialize it to get in original form.